# How to inflate Context Menu from Onclickitem?

Tags: java, android, android-contextmenu

I am trying to inflate a Context Menu from this code. The program runs, however, whenever I click on an item nothing happens. This is the code I am using. Could you please help me figure out what's wrong? The name of the menu I am trying to open is called "testmenu".

```
package com.carouseldemo.main;

import com.carouseldemo.controls.Carousel;
import com.carouseldemo.controls.CarouselAdapter;
import com.carouseldemo.controls.CarouselItem;
import com.carouseldemo.controls.CarouselAdapter.OnItemClickListener;
import com.carouseldemo.controls.CarouselAdapter.OnItemSelectedListener;
import com.carouseldemo.main.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
 @Override
  public void onCreateContextMenu (ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.testmenu, menu);
  }


/** Called when the activity is first created. */

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);




    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.radio);

    mp.start();
    Carousel carousel = (Carousel)findViewById(R.id.carousel);
    carousel.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

        public void onItemClick(CarouselAdapter<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {    
            registerForContextMenu(view);
            openContextMenu(view);


        }

        @Override
        public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                CoTell me please, whenntextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }



    });




    carousel.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(){

        public void onItemSelected(CarouselAdapter<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {



            final TextView txt = (TextView)(findViewById(R.id.selected_item));

            switch(position){
            case 0:
                txt.setText("Power Source International ");
                break;
            case 1:
                txt.setText("Power Source International");
                break;
            case 2:
                txt.setText("Power Source International");
                break;
            case 3:
                txt.setText("Power Source International.");
                break;
            case 4:
                txt.setText("Power Source International");
            case 5:
                txt.setText("Power Source InternationalPower Source InternationalPower Source InternationalPower Source InternationalPower Source InternationalPower Source InternationalPower Source InternationalPower Source InternationalPower Source InternationalPower Source InternationalPower Source InternationalPower Source InternationalPower Source InternationalPower Source International");
                break;
            }

        }

        public void onNothingSelected(CarouselAdapter<?> parent) {
        }

    }
    );

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}



}
```

If it will help, here is the code for the menu as well.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/new_game"
      android:icon="@drawable/cat"
      android:title="@string/new_game"
      android:showAsAction="ifRoom" android:checkable="true" android:enabled="true"         android:visible="true"/>
<item android:id="@+id/help"
      android:icon="@drawable/cat"
      android:title="@string/help" />
```

How do I open this menu in my activity? The menu will not come up when I click an item.

Comment: You should probably take out the empty `onCreateContextMenu()` (the one that doesn't inflate *anything*). And put a debug statement, such as a `Toast` in `onItemClick()` (make sure to call `.show()` on the Toast. To see if first, that method is even being called.

Comment: Which one? super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);  "or"               @Override
        public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

Comment: The `// TODO Auto-generated method stub`

Comment: It says it is an inherited abstract method for carousel.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){  It ask me to reimplement it when I remove it.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with this source, but it seems that you should move the inflation to this method. But then I wonder, how do you call it? Is [this](http://code.google.com/p/android-carousel-demo/source/browse/CarouselDemo/src/com/carouseldemo/controls/CarouselItem.java?r=3) the source for Carousel?

Comment: This is the source code. I should move the inflation to which method? http://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/ViewDownloads.aspx?aid=146145

Comment: I just looked at what you posted. Yes, that is also the source.

Comment: I don't know why Eclipse is forcing you to add in an override for a context menu *inside* the Listener, [their example MainAcivity](http://code.google.com/p/android-carousel-demo/source/browse/CarouselDemo/src/com/carouseldemo/main/MainActivity.java) does not force it. Also, I must ask this, since I'm not clear - do you want the context menu to pop up as soon as the user clicks on an item or when they press and hold?

Comment: As soon as the user presses on an item, I want a context menu to pop up. Or some kind of menu I can use for content. When I remove the onCreateContextMenu that "does not inflate anything" this is the exact wording of the error if it will help: The type new CarouselAdapter.OnItemClickListener(){} must implement the inherited abstract method CarouselAdapter.OnItemClickListener.onCreateContextMenu(Context Menu, View, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo)

Comment: Downloaded the source and Eclipse does not prompt me to add `onCreateContextMenu()` for the `ItemClickListener()` so I suggest cleaning your project and restarting Eclipse/your IDE. Also, take out `registerForContextMenu (view);` and instead write `registerForContextMenu(carousel);` **above** `carousel.setOnItemClickListener...` [I copied what I have](http://pastebin.com/pKgn5tGc) so you can have a look.

Comment: You've cracked the case! Thank you so much, you have no idea how much you have helped me so far when no one else would. If it isn't too much trouble, may I ask how to open this menu only when one of the six items are clicked? And open an independent, separate menu for when each of the other items are clicked? Again, I can't thank you enough honestly.

Comment: You would probably have to have an if statement and if it matches what you want: inflate `menu A`, otherwise inflate `menu B`. I don't think it'd be too hard.

Comment: Where would I put the if statement?

Comment: Most likely in `onCreateContextMenu()`. You should try things out.